# Equivalent of FFTW's fftw_plan_r2r_2d in KISS FFT

Tags: ios, fft, fftw, kissfft, accelerate

Currently I am using  FFTW's  "fftw_plan_r2r_2d" with FFTW_REDFT10 as a kind and FFTW_ESTIMATE as the flag in my project. I am thinking of using KISSFFT for the transforms.I need the set of calls needed to perform the same operation in KISS FFT.

I am developing an ios app,So I want to know if its possible to use ios Accelerate Framework for the transform.

Answer (score 0):

From [FFTW docs](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real_002dto_002dReal-Transform-Kinds.html)

> FFTW_REDFT10 computes an REDFT10 transform, i.e. a DCT-II (sometimes called “the” DCT). (Logical N=2*n, inverse is FFTW_REDFT01.)

kissfft does not directly support the DCT, just FFTs.  Some DCTs can be trivially adapted to/from the real-version FFT/IFFT with trivial manipulation, but I cannot recall if DCT-II is one of these.

Comment: I found out this link http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/fast-cosine-transform-via-fft I am new to this so don't know whether it is possible to do it or not.The link however says that we can compute DCT 2 from FFT.I tried the first approach Type 2 DCT using 4N FFT and no shifts but found different result